# What is the correct way to calculate error for MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

The output for network which recognizes MNIST database is predictions for 10 classes, i.e. for 1000 images we will have matrix of size (1000, 10). Which way represents cost function better (and why?):

- simple `tf.squared_difference(Y_pred, Y_pred)`?
- mean over batches `tf.reduce_mean(tf.tf.squared_difference(Y_pred, Y_pred), axis=0)`
- or mean over classes and then over batches `tf.reduce_men(tf.reduce_mean(tf.tf.squared_difference(Y_pred, Y_pred), axis=1))`

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.  Show your work, reduce the open problem to a small, single point, and then you're ready for help on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Since your targets are categories (numbers from 0 to 9), it is better to use a [cross entropy cost function](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html), and do something like that:

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(Y_pred + 1e-10))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Here `Y` are the real target values, and `Y_pred` are the predicted target values.
Here is a [discussion](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/) of the benefits of cross entropy over mean square error for classification problems.